# Select one row with distinct value of one column

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

This is the data

```
id    name     start_date    end_date    merchant_id
===================================================
111   name1    25-nov-11    31-jan-12    9999
222   name2    23-nov-11    25-dec-11    9999
333   name3    25-nov-11    25-nov-12    9999
444   name4    20-nov-11    20-nov-11    9999
555   name5    25-nov-11    25-dec-11    8888
666   name6    19-oct-11    20-nov-11    8888
777   name7    20-nov-11    20-jun-12    8888
```

I need to get all rows sorted by `start_date` (desc) where `start_date<=today` and `end_date >=today` but limit 1 per `merchant_id`. Which means if the query finds more than one row, then just return the first one.

---

Test script

```
CREATE TABLE DEAL
(
  ID            VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)       NOT NULL,
  NAME          VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
  START_DATE    DATE,
  END_DATE      DATE,
  MERCHANT_ID   NUMBER(22),
 CONSTRAINT DEAL PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT ALL
INTO DEAL (ID,NAME,START_DATE,END_DATE,MERCHANT_ID) VALUES ('111','name1','25-nov-11','31-jan-12','9999')
INTO DEAL (ID,NAME,START_DATE,END_DATE,MERCHANT_ID) VALUES ('222','name2','23-nov-11','25-dec-11','9999')
INTO DEAL (ID,NAME,START_DATE,END_DATE,MERCHANT_ID) VALUES ('333','name3','25-nov-11','25-nov-12','9999')
INTO DEAL (ID,NAME,START_DATE,END_DATE,MERCHANT_ID) VALUES ('444','name4','20-nov-11','20-nov-11','9999')
INTO DEAL (ID,NAME,START_DATE,END_DATE,MERCHANT_ID) VALUES ('555','name5','25-nov-11','25-dec-11','8888')
INTO DEAL (ID,NAME,START_DATE,END_DATE,MERCHANT_ID) VALUES ('666','name6','19-oct-11','20-nov-11','8888')
INTO DEAL (ID,NAME,START_DATE,END_DATE,MERCHANT_ID) VALUES ('777','name7','20-nov-11','20-jun-12','8888')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

---

running this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT merchant_id, id, name, start_date, end_date FROM deal WHERE start_date <= trunc(sysdate) AND end_date >= trunc(sysdate) ORDER BY start_date DESC;
```

does not return the desired result as the same merchant id is returned multiple times:

```
MERCHANT_ID  ID  NAME  START_DATE  END_DATE 
===========================================
9999         111  name1  25-NOV-11  31-JAN-12  
9999         333  name3  25-NOV-11  25-NOV-12 
8888         555  name5  25-NOV-11  25-DEC-11  
9999         222  name2  23-NOV-11  25-DEC-11  
8888         777  name7  20-NOV-11  20-JUN-12
```

Comment: you can use BETWEEN clause instead of start_date<=today and end_date >=today.

Comment: I've been trying various statements with distinct, limit, group by.. but haven't been able to get any to work. I can get the all rows with the appropriate start and end date but don't know how to one return 1 row per merchant_id

Comment: Which database are you using? if you are using Oracle one solution is use analytic functions

Comment: What version of SQL (mySQL) or Microsoft SQL or Oracle, etc.

Comment: @BCatguystats Given your table that you posted, can you also post what you expect the results of your query to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Oracle query should do what you need:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TABLE1.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY MERCHANT_ID ORDER BY START_DATE DESC, ID) R
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN START_DATE AND END_DATE
)
WHERE R = 1
ORDER BY START_DATE DESC
```

Essentially, it first filters rows by date and then ignores all rows but the *first* one that share the same MERCHANT_ID.

Please note that the meaning of "first" is defined relative to descending START_DATE order. It two rows have same START_DATE, then the "dispute" is resolved using ID order.

Answer (score 0):

Hi something like this could work:

```
select id,    name,     start_date,    end_date from (
select id,    name,     start_date,    end_date, ROW_NUMBER()
   OVER (PARTITION BY merchant_id ORDER BY merchant_id) AS rnum from your_table
   where start_date<=trunc(sysdate) and end_date>=trunc(sysdate))
   where rnum=1
order by start_date desc
```

if you provide a simple test script for creating and populating the table I can give you the correct query.

Comment: Test script added to original post.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what type of sql you are running (mysql, sql server, etc) there will be alternate answers.

For example, in sql server you could say "Assign each row a number, starting at 1 for each merchant", and always pick number 1.

In generic sql, you have to be a little less direct.  It appears your id column is guaranteed to be unique?  If so one way of phrasing the question is "get records inside the date range WHERE there is no higher id in the same date range for the same merchant"

Do you know already how to filter by > and < today?  I think the answer to how to do that is specific to what type of sql you're using:

So try:

```
SELECT * from myFavoriteTable
  WHERE today() < end_date and today > start_date -- for this date criteria use whatever works
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * from myFavoriteTable as TooLow
      WHERE today() < end_date and today() > start_date -- as above
      AND TooLow.Merchant = myFavoriteTable.merchant
      AND TooLow.id > myFavoriteTable.id)
```

Answer (score -2):

All of these other answers seem extra complicated... You can use the `DISTINCT` modifier in Oracle to get one and only one unique row per a specific column. Here is a query that you could use to retrieve the data you want, given the table structure in your post:

`SELECT DISTINCT merchant_id, id, name, start_date, end_date FROM table WHERE start_date >= today AND end_date < today ORDER BY start_date DESC`

Comment: This does not return the required results
SELECT DISTINCT merchant_id, id, name, start_date, end_date FROM deal WHERE start_date <= trunc(sysdate) AND end_date >= trunc(sysdate) ORDER BY start_date DESC;

Comment: Does not return distinct rows for a single column